# Checking array in Athena

Tags: arrays, amazon-athena

I have a table in Athena where one of the columns is of type `array<string>`. However, when I run

```
select * from mytable
where array_contains(myarr,'foobar')
limit 10
```

it seems Athena doesn't have the `array_contains` function:

```
SYNTAX_ERROR: line 2:7: Function array_contains not registered
```

Is there an alternative way to check if the array contains a particular string?

Comment: Why are you trying to use `array_contains`?

Comment: Thanks @DuduMarkovitz ! I was looking into Hive and this seemed to be the suggested function to use for checking an array. I didn't see or try `contains`, but that works.

Comment: Please bear with me. I'm trying to figure out something. Why did you think that Hive is relevant here?

Comment: In retrospect, I realized that Athena just uses the Hive metastore, but before I was thinking Hive functions were available also. Now I realize I should reference Presto's docs.

Comment: Exactly :-) I see this happens a lot

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
select * 
from   mytable
where  contains(myarr,'foobar')
limit  10
```

Answer (score 0):

Athena supports two ways to filter array data ***contains()*** , ***filter()*** find more details https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/filtering-arrays.html

- contains(*array*, *data*) - apply condition in where clause.

```
select * 
from   mytable
where  contains(myarr,'foobar')
```

- filter() - Create sub-array based on filter condition

```
filter(ARRAY [list_of_values], boolean_function)

SELECT filter(ARRAY [1,0,5,-1], x -> x>0)
```